# How to use input processor and output processor in add_xpath

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

My code is:

```
ldr.add_xpath('name', u'//div[@id="name"]/h1/text()', MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip()), TakeFirst())
```

But TakeFirst() has no effect. Why?

Comment: What's your input? What's your actual output and expected output?

Comment: Input is a list, and output is the first item in list. But it returns a list, not the first item.

Comment: Does MapCompose() without TakeFirst() work as expected? Does TakeFirst() alone also have the same result (no effect)? Can you post more code (spider, items definition and item loaders) and console output?